# Elastic APM HTTP error (404): 404 page not found

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

Getting error while integrating Elastic APM in the Node Express application.
Nodejs: v6.4.2,

**app.js**

```
require('elastic-apm-node').start({
  serviceName: config.apm_node.SERVICE_NAME,
  secretToken: config.apm_node.SECRET_TOKEN,
  serverUrl: config.apm_node.SERVER_URL,
  environment: config.apm_node.ENV,
});
```

**package.json**

```
"elastic-apm-node":"^1.14.4"
```

**Error:**

> You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
>   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
>       at /home/ubuntu/depanels/server/api/user/user.controller.js:22:25
>       at /home/ubuntu/depanels/server/auth/auth.service.js:149:28
>       at _fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
>       at /home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
>       at runSingle (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
>       at elasticAPMCallbackWrapper (/home/ubuntu/depanels/node_modules/elastic-apm-node/lib/instrumentation/index.js:191:27)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (node.js:389:13)
>   Elastic APM HTTP error (404): 404 page not found
>   Elastic APM HTTP error (404): 404 page not found

Please suggest where I am doing wrong?